# Looking if a Value(in a list) is in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have this dictionary with keys and values but I have more values added to a key.

```
dictionary = {"Key": ["Wauw", "Wow","What"], "Key2": ["Pretty", "Weak"]}
"Wauw" in dictionary
```

This doesn't work

Comment: `"Wauw" in list(itertools.chain(*(dictionary.values())))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest Version without import would be:

```py
>>> dictionary = {"Key": ["Wauw", "Wow","What"], "Key2": ["Pretty", "Weak"]}
>>> 'Wauw' in [x for v in dictionary.values() for x in v]
True

# The list comrehensions result:
>>> print( [x for v in dictionary.values() for x in v] )
['Wauw', 'Wow', 'What', 'Pretty', 'Weak']
```

Another possibility would be:

```py
>>> any(['Wauw' in lst for lst in dictionary.values()])
True
```

---

As there was a little performance question I tested the different versions for their execution speed:

```
# List-Comprehension: 'Wauw' in [x for v in dictionary.values() for x in v]
python -m timeit -s 'dictionary = {"Key": ["Wauw", "Wow","What"], "Key2": ["Pretty", "Weak"]}' "'Wauw' in [x for v in dictionary.values() for x in v]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.398 usec per loop

# Generator: (x for v in dictionary.values() for x in v)
python -m timeit -s 'dictionary = {"Key": ["Wauw", "Wow","What"], "Key2": ["Pretty", "Weak"]}' "'Wauw' in (x for v in dictionary.values() for x in v)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.639 usec per loop

# any(['Wauw' in lst for lst in dictionary.values()])
python -m timeit -s 'dictionary = {"Key": ["Wauw", "Wow","What"], "Key2": ["Pretty", "Weak"]}' "any(['Wauw' in lst for lst in dictionary.values()])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.272 usec per loop

# Itertools version from user8408080 without measuring the import
python -m timeit -s 'from itertools import chain;dictionary = {"Key": ["Wauw", "Wow","What"], "Key2": ["Pretty", "Weak"]}' "'Wauw' in chain(*dictionary.values())"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.33 usec per loop

# Itertools version from user8408080 import is recognized in the measuring
python -m timeit -s 'dictionary = {"Key": ["Wauw", "Wow","What"], "Key2": ["Pretty", "Weak"]}' "from itertools import chain; 'Wauw' in chain(*dictionary.values())"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 usec per loop
```

Comment: I like the idea with `any`. But still, on my machine, this takes `401ns ± 1.7ns` compared to `283ns ± 2.35ns` for the `itertools` solution

Comment: Good argument. How is it with the encapsulated list comprehension above? Should be faster. At least if you include the import into 5he measuring.

Comment: Well if you add in the import, my solution definitely becomes slower for such small samples, but I would argue, that this effect diminishes for larger dicts

Comment: In my tests (look above) the any variant was supriseingly the fastest one.

Comment: When adding the import to the calculation, this seems legitimate to me. As I said above, I would guess, that the `itertools` solution will become faster for larger dictionaries compared to the other solutions. With a dictionary this small, the perfomance not really important :D
So for a little script, I would prefer the `any` solution, for large dictionaries I guess the `itertools`  solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

A check like you did would only search in the keys. What you want is to chain the values and search in the result of that:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> dictionary = {"Key": ["Wauw", "Wow","What"], "Key2": ["Pretty", "Weak"]}
>>> "Wauw" in chain(*dictionary.values())
True
```

Without importing a module:

```
>>> check = []
>>> for el in dictionary.values():
...     check += el
>>> "Wauw" in check
True
```

Comment: Is there also a way without importing a module?

Comment: @JanvanOverbeek I added an option without any import, but I strongly suggest the first option. `itertools` is a standard library, that comes with any python installation.